# Создание кастомного адаптера Android — ошибка

Tags: java, android

Не могу понять как делать кастомный адаптер. Вот попробовал сделать как понял, но выходит ошибка при запуске приложения! 
Layout'ов 2 — в одном ListView, а в другом четыре TextView на вертикальном LinearLayout.

Вот листинг:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private MyList myList1;
    private MyList myList2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        myList1 = new MyList("abc", "a333412", "312421", "12314124");
        myList2 = new MyList("gewg", "gewgewas", "gweewwe", "gdshgweh");

        List<MyList> myLists = new ArrayList<MyList>();

        myLists.add(myList1);
        myLists.add(myList2);

        ArrayAdapter<MyList> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyList>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_layout, myLists);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);    
    }
}


public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private List<MyList> list;

    public MyAdapter (Context context, List<MyList> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_layout, R.id.textView1, list);
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout,
                parent, false);

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView textView3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView textView4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        MyList myList = list.get(position);

        textView1.setText(myList.getA1().toString());
        textView2.setText(myList.getA2().toString());
        textView3.setText(myList.getA3().toString());
        textView4.setText(myList.getA3().toString());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

В классе MyList четыре переменных типа String, геттеры-сеттеры, конструктор из всех 4 переменных и пустой конструктор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class SampleListViewAdapterAllGroup extends BaseAdapter {

    public static Context context;
    ArrayList<String> data;
    public SampleListViewAdapterAllGroup(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final View twoLineListItem;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            twoLineListItem = (View) inflater.inflate(com.akscorp.blueboard.R.layout.all_group_listview_space, null);
        } else {
            twoLineListItem = (View) convertView;
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) twoLineListItem.findViewById(com.akscorp.blueboard.R.id.group_name);

        return twoLineListItem;
    }
    }
```

У вас неверный шаблон адаптера. Он должен наследоваться как выше. Выше и приведен шаблон адаптера

В вашем случае должно выглядеть примерно так

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<MyList> list;

    public MyAdapter (Context context, List<MyList> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout,
                parent, false);

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView textView3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView textView4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        MyList myList = list.get(position);

        textView1.setText(myList.getA1().toString());
        textView2.setText(myList.getA2().toString());
        textView3.setText(myList.getA3().toString());
        textView4.setText(myList.getA3().toString());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Ну и вызывать можно так

```
 listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(context));
```